# Style DataTrigger not updating Custom Control Dependency Property

Tags: wpf, custom-controls

I've defined a custom control that allows me to draw a series of arcs that result in a segmented circle. In this control I've defined a dependency property that allows me to set the number of segments to draw, i.e.,

```
public int SegmentCount
{
  get => (int) GetValue( SegmentCountProperty );
  set => SetValue( SegmentCountProperty, value );
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty SegmentCountProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register( nameof(SegmentCount), typeof( int ), typeof( MyCustomControl ), new PropertyMetadata( 1 ) );
```

I want to set this property in xaml according to a data trigger defined in a style as follows

```
<Style x:Key="MyCustomControlStyle" TargetType="local:MyCustomControl">
    <Setter Property="SegmentCount" Value="0"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsActive}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="SegmentCount" Value="4"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsActive}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="SegmentCount" Value="0"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

However, the "False" DataTrigger that attempts to set the `SegmentCount` property back to 0 doesn't appear to update the view. If I set the `Stroke` property as well (which i don't want to do) like this

```
<Style x:Key="MyCustomControlStyle" TargetType="local:MyCustomControl">
    <Setter Property="SegmentCount" Value="0"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsActive}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="SegmentCount" Value="4"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsActive}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="SegmentCount" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Green"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

It seems to kick things along and I get the expected view, albeit with the wrong colour now. Is there a reason why my Dependency property is not updating the view in this scenario? Do I have to tell the framework it has changed similar to a RaiseNotifyProperty changed event?

Comment: 1) Is `IsActive` a property of the custom control, or a property of the custom control's DataContext? You're binding to the latter, unless you're setting `DataContext = this` somewhere (which is harmful and unnecessary). 2) Are you explicitly setting `SegmentCount` on the control via an attribute on the instance itself in the XAML when you create the control? (e.g. `<local:MyCustomControl SegmentCount="3" />`) That will override anything the style does to the property, due to dependency property value precedence.

Comment: A dependency property raises its own change notifications. You don't need to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `PropertyChangedCallback` registered for the `SegmentCount` property.

It probably just does not trigger rendering. Try to set `Framework​Property​Metadata​Options.AffectsRender`:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SegmentCountProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(SegmentCount), typeof(int), typeof(MyCustomControl),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            1, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));
```

Comment: Yep, that did it. Decompiling the DependencyProperty source for the WPF's stroke property also shed more light on the world of `FrameworkPropertyMetadata'

Comment: @JamesB Depending on the overall complexity of your control, it might perhaps be more efficient to only update the affected Geometry in a PropertyChangedCallback instead of re-rendering the whole control.